# Минимальное значение из массива + рандом

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как получать РАНДОМНОЕ минимальное значение из массива, если ОДИНАКОВЫХ минимальных значений может быть от одного до бесконечности
к примеру есть массив(Первое это ID второе это значение которое надо найти):

> 666 - 3145
>
> 45 - 3145
>
> 36 - 100000
>
> 45 - 89898

Сейчас я получаю просто минимальное значение таким способом.
Где $dist - массив с со значениями и ИД

```
$min_value=min($dist);
$key = array_search($min_value, $dist); 
echo $idd[$key]." - ";
echo $min_value;
```

Надо что бы при обновлении было к примеру сначала 666 - 3145, а при следующем обновлении 45 - 3145.....Ну т.е. что бы из массива получал минимальное значение рандомом

Comment: Вам надо использовать [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php) с указанным вторым параметром. А уже из этих ключей и выбираете рандомный

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можете минимальные значения поместить в массив `$minArray`, затем выбирать элемент массива случайно от `0..n`, где `n` - `(длинна $minArray) - 1`.